# Convert Current Date to Unix timestamp but using Days

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, epoch, solaris-10

In Solaris, I am trying to write a shell script that converts current date to the number of days after 1/1/1970 for Unix. This is because etc/shadow isn't using Epoch time but instead a 'days format'

i.e "root:G9yPfhFAqvlsI:15841::::::" where the 15841 is a date.

So in essence what command do I use to find out the epoch time for now and then convert that to days.

Comment: What is 15841? The number of seconds after the Epoch began? If so, you should be able to divide it by 60*60*24 to get the number of days.

Comment: 15841 is the number of days after 1/1/1970 so I'm trying to find out what the command is to print today's date into the format for days @ahoffer

Comment: You can use `echo $(($(nawk 'BEGIN {print srand()}') / 86400 ))`.

Comment: @alvits, that's good, you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some pseudo code to calculate it from the basics:

```
if month > 2 then
  month=month+1
else
  month=month+13
  year=year-1
fi

day=(year*365)+(year/4)-(year/100)+(year/400)+(month*306001/10000)+day
days_since_epoch=day-719591
```

Credit: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/115449-how-convert-date-time-epoch-time-solaris.html). On the same forum thread, another poster said this would work in Solaris:

```
truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | grep ^time | awk -F"= " '{print $2}'
```

Comment: i put 'truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | grep ^time | awk -F"= " '{print $2}'' into a variable now do you know how I would divide that variable using the "variable" /8600 ?

Comment: @user3508234 - it will be easier to use nawk's srand(). If you are running bash you can assign to var like `(( var = $(nawk 'BEGIN {print srand()}') / 86400 ))`. If you still prefer the above method, you can use `(( var /= 86400 ))` on bash or `var=\`echo $var / 86400 | bc\`` on non-bash.

Comment: @user3508234: `truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | nawk '$1 == "time()" {print int($NF/86400)}'`

Comment: @alvits, might as well do the division in awk: `nawk 'BEGIN {print int(srand()/86400)}'`

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have GNU tools, which might make things easier. This is simple enough though:

```
perl -le 'print int(time/86400)'
```

Comment: If you're using this to obtain a uid, better not create 2 users on the same day.

Comment: Thank you @glennjackman 
is there anyway to do this without perl?

Answer (score 0):

Solaris `date` utility doesn't support `%s` format. However, `nawk` utility has `srand()` function that returns date in seconds when there's no parameter passed to it.

```
nawk 'BEGIN {print srand()}'
```

Results in

```
1405529923
```

To get the days instead of seconds, you can divide the result by 86400.

```
nawk 'BEGIN {printf("%d", srand() / 86400)}'
```